# Referencing a Schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I am trying to reference student information to the user schema. For the user schema, I am using passports local for authentication. I am trying to make the user info unique to each user, and its connection with the student info which contains the name and other details. I try to register the user, then find it by id and populate it with the student schema. Right now it doesn't show any errors, but when I look at the users in the database, the student info is not connected to it. Please help

```
User Schema
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    usersInfo: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'StudentInfo'
        }
});
UserSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);
UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);

Student Info Schema
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

var StudentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    first_name: String,
    middle_name: String,
    last_name: String,
    street: String,
    town: String,
    city: String,
    region: String,
    country: String,
    studentId: String,
    day: Number,
    month: String,
    year: Number,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("StudentInfo", StudentSchema);

my routes for both the create student infos and register users

var StudentInfo      = require("./models/studentInfo"),
    User      = require("./models/user");

app.post('/signup', function(req,res){

    StudentInfo.create(req.body.studentInfo, function(err, newlycreated){
        if(err) {
            res.redirect('back');
        }
        else {
            res.redirect('/register');
        }
   });
});

app.post('/register', function(req, res) {
    var user = {username: req.body.username};

    User.register(user, req.body.password, function(err, user){

        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.redirect('back');
               }
        else {
            //console.log(user._id);
            User.findById(user._id).populate('StudentInfo').exec(function(err, found) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.redirect('back');
                    }
            else {
                 //console.log(User.studentInfo.first_name);
                 res.redirect('/');

            }

            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html):

> Population is the process of automatically replacing the specified paths in the document with document(s) from other collection(s).

So you need to specify the **path**, not the collection name. The below should work:

```
User.findById(user._id).populate('usersInfo')...
```